# Second monitor stopped working after executing dist-upgrade

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, multiple-monitors, amdgpu

I'm using a newly installed `Xubuntu 21.10` on my brand new `ASUS ROG Zephyrus G14 GA401QM-K2030T`. It has two video cards. One is the integrated on the AMD CPU `Ryzen™ 9 5900HX` and the second one is a discrete `NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060`. I also using an external monitor alongside laptop one via the HDMI port. Initially, the setup was working fine, but after executing `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and restarting the external monitor has stopped working. Could someone give any suggestions on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: im seeing same issue after upgrade to 21.04 and then to 21.10

Comment: @debianmaster Is the laptop working fine with the 21.04?

Comment: works intermittentantly . very buggy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a problem with NVIDIA drivers. I logged in to a text terminal and type `sudo apt remove --purge nvidia*` and then reboot. Then I reinstalled the Nvidia drivers.